# Parametrising a Sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If parametrising a sphere $r=(\cos{u}\cos{v},\cos{u}\sin{v},\sin{u})$ is it true that limits for $u$ and $v$ will be $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ and $0$ and $2\pi$ respectively? Why is this different to when parametrising a sphere, with parametrization $\rho\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}, \rho\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}, \rho\cos{\phi}$ where the limits of $\phi$ are between and $0$ and $\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost the same with $\rho=1$ (unit sphere) and $\phi=\pi/2-u$ $v=\theta$

Comment: Thank you, how does this change when not the unit sphere?

Comment: You have to multiply by $\rho\neq 1$

Comment: But does this affect the angles of phi in anyway? @marwalix

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that, I meant, if it was not centred at the origin

Comment: No not at all you can the set $(\phi,\theta)$ or $(u,v)$ for the angle parameters. If it is not centered at the origin you just need to translate by a vector $(a,b,c)$. So the most general parametrisation of a sphere centered in $(a,b,c)$ with radius $\rho$ would be $(a+\rho\sin{\phi}\cos{\theta},b+\rho\cos{\phi}\cos{\theta},c+\rho\sin{\theta})$

Comment: @anon There are various ways to deal with a sphere not centered at the origin. I recommend asking a new question specifically about spherical coordinates and spheres not centered at the origin if you are interested in that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a co-ordinate change via substitution:
substitute $u = \pi/2 - \phi$ and then adjust the range of the $u$ value accordingly. I.e:

$-\pi/2 \leq u \leq \pi/2$ becomes $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$.

Note: $cos(\pi/2 - \phi) = sin(\phi)$ and $sin(\pi/2 - \phi) = cos(\phi)$.

This is simply a rotation of the co-ordinate system , but since spheres are symmetric it is invariant under rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain my intuition using diagrams , I just see it as difference of angle. As sphere is symmetric both of them gives same result. Moreover, here we just defined $\phi$ to be a different angle but in the end $z$ coordinate is same

[image]

Sorry for the bad diagrams, i am on laptop.

Here as you can see $cos \phi$ moves along only one direction clockwise or anticlockwise whereas $sin \phi$ has to move toward up as well as down, moreover think of their respective domain.

Comment: In other words, $\phi$ is zero at the positive $z$ axis and increases as you move "down" toward the $xy$ plane and finally to the negative $z$ axis; but $u$ is zero everywhere on the $xy$ plane and has to increase to reach positive $z$ values and decrease to reach negative $z$.

Answer (score 0):

A useful exercise might be to consider these six points in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates:

$$(A,0,0)_{x,y,z}$$
$$(0,A,0)_{x,y,z}$$
$$(0,0,A)_{x,y,z}$$
$$(-A,0,0)_{x,y,z}$$
$$(0,-A,0)_{x,y,z}$$
$$(0,0,-A)_{x,y,z}$$

Write each of these in standard $(\rho,\phi,\theta)$ spherical coordinates.
Then write the same point in $(r,u,v)$ coordinates,
where $x=r\cos u \cos v,$ $y = r \cos u \sin v,$ and $z = r \sin u.$
Then you'll see how the coordinate systems relate to one another
and why the range of $u$ is different from the range of $\phi$.

The six points have been chosen so that it will be easy to guess the correct
values of the sines and cosines in every case.
This is not meant to be a difficult exercise.